# Case sensitive UriMapper issue in Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0, navigation, case-sensitive

In Navigation API of Silverlight 3 the UriMapper class is case sensitive. For the following uri mapping

```
<nav:Frame Source="/Home">
  <nav:Frame.UriMapper>
    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
      <uriMapper:UriMapping
        Uri=""
        MappedUri="/Views/HomePage.xaml"/>
      <uriMapper:UriMapping
        Uri="/entity/{code}"
        MappedUri="/Views/EntityEditorPage.xaml?code={code}"/>
      <uriMapper:UriMapping
        Uri="/{pageName}"
        MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}Page.xaml"/>
    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
  </nav:Frame.UriMapper>
</nav:Frame>
```

the "/entity/123" is correctly mapping to "/Views/EntityEditorPage.xaml?code=123"
but "/Entity/123" will fail with the "/Views/Entity/123Page.xaml not found" exception.

How can I turn the UriMapper to case-insensitive?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safor,

I did exactly what Anthony suggested for my own application.

Here is your XAML modified to use a CustomUriMapper:

```
<nav:Frame Source="/Home">
    <nav:Frame.UriMapper>
        <app:CustomUriMapper>
            <app:CustomUriMapping Uri="" MappedUri="/Views/HomePage.xaml"/>
            <app:CustomUriMapping Uri="/entity/{code}" MappedUri="/Views/EntityEditorPage.xaml?code={code}"/>
            <app:CustomUriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}Page.xaml"/>
        </app:CustomUriMapper>
    </nav:Frame.UriMapper>
</nav:Frame>
```

Here is the code for the CustomUriMapping and the CustomUriMapper classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Markup;
using System.Windows.Navigation;

namespace YourApplication
{
    // In XAML:
    // <app:CustomUriMapper>
    //     <app:CustomUriMapping Uri="/{search}" MappedUri="/Views/searchpage.xaml?searchfor={search}"/>
    // </app:CustomUriMapper>

    public class CustomUriMapping
    {
        public Uri Uri { get; set; }
        public Uri MappedUri { get; set; }

        public Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
        {
            // Do the uri mapping without regard to upper or lower case
            UriMapping _uriMapping = new UriMapping() { Uri = (Uri == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Uri.OriginalString) ? null : new Uri(Uri.OriginalString.ToLower(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)), MappedUri = MappedUri };
            return _uriMapping.MapUri(uri == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(uri.OriginalString) ? null : new Uri(uri.OriginalString.ToLower(), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }

    [ContentProperty("UriMappings")]
    public class CustomUriMapper : UriMapperBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CustomUriMapping> UriMappings { get { return m_UriMappings; } private set { m_UriMappings = value; } }
        private ObservableCollection<CustomUriMapping> m_UriMappings = new ObservableCollection<CustomUriMapping>();

        public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
        {
            if (m_UriMappings == null)
                return uri;

            foreach (CustomUriMapping mapping in m_UriMappings)
            {
                Uri mappedUri = mapping.MapUri(uri);
                if (mappedUri != null)
                    return mappedUri;
            }

            return uri;
        }
    }
}
```

Good luck, Jim McCurdy

Comment: Jim, thank you for the code. It works!
Just one note. It is necessary to specify parameters in lower case only.

-Eugene

Comment: Hmm, I'm confused.  The whole point is that this UriMapper performs case-insentsitive Uri checking.  Which parameters are you specifiying as lower case?

Comment: Jim, sorry, I missed your question.
I meant parameters like {search}
With the code above you cannot use {searchArg} one, but {searcharg} will work. Just that.

Answer (score 1):

UriMapper uses regular expression try changing your mapping to "[V|v]iews/EntityEditorPage.xaml?code={code}" for starters this will make the V in view case insensi

Comment: The mapping should be "[Vv]iews/EntityEditorPage.xaml?code={code}". Otherwise the Url "|iews/EntityEditorPage.xaml?code={code}" would also match.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this easily.  Ultimately you will need to derive your own `UriMapperBase` and do all the mapping logic yourself.  Its probably not a worthwhile thing to do unless you can use some simplified mappings.