# Silverlight navigation frame - regex like uri mapping configuration problem

Tags: .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, navigation

I have an idea of URI structure for my app so if it ends with lets say `#Home` it will navigate to main frame. If however it ends with something like `#{\d\d\d}` (regex for 3 digits here) , it will navigate to `#Home` and pass those 3 digits as a parameter.

I don't think navigation framework supports regexes for `{parameters}` in curly brackets and it generally expects something like `#Home/{id}` in URI mapping. and if i simply do `#{id}` mapping  `#Home` and even `#AnotherPage` will be caught into that too.

If I want to stick to my plan for URI how could I achieve that, the simplest way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could implement a custom urimapper to achieve this.  Check this out as an example: [Case sensitive UriMapper issue in Silverlight 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155614/case-sensitive-urimapper-issue-in-silverlight-3)

..or

You could try something like

`<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Views/{myVar}Home" MappedUri="/Views/MainFrame.xaml"/>`

`<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/Views/{myVar}" MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml?myVar={myVar}"/>`

then, in Home.xaml.cs, you should be able to do the following:

```
  this.Loaded += Home_Loaded;
    ...
   public void Home_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("myVar"))
     var v = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["myVar"]; 
     //Now examine v.  If it is in the correct format \d\d\d then continue.
     //Else...redirect or throw exception
   }
```

Comment: I guess it could be it, if there is no other way

Comment: hmm in that thread some guy is saying that it uses regex expression, is that correct? shouldn't that help solve my issue if that is true?